# Fatal error or could not launch JNLP

Tags: java, ubuntu, jnlp

I am trying  to access data [here](http://pcmdi9.llnl.gov/esgf-web-fe/)

as per the steps mentioned in [here](https://modelingguru.nasa.gov/docs/DOC-2312)

The step 4 requires me to start the JNLP, and I dont have any knowledge on JAVA so I dont have any knowledge on what this error saying.

Please let me know if any one of you have any idea on this. It will be a great help. [I am using UBUNTU]

Here is the error log:

**net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Launch Error: Could not launch JNLP file. The application has not been initialized, for more information execute javaws/browser from the command line and send a bug report.     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:577)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:911) Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: no manifiest section for signature file entry org/bouncycastle/asn1/ocsp/ResponderID.class     at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.verifySection(SignatureFileVerifier.java:446)     at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:297)     at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:240)     at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:274)     at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:228)     at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:348)     at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:415)     at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(URLClassPath.java:775)     at sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream(Resource.java:77)     at sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer(Resource.java:160)     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:436)     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.access$1701(JNLPClassLoader.java:103)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader$5.run(JNLPClassLoader.java:1636)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader$5.run(JNLPClassLoader.java:1634)     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1633)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.loadClassExt(JNLPClassLoader.java:1670)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1471)     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)     at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2856)     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1668)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:554)     ... 1 more**

I tried to launch the JNLP manually from the command line but all I get is a flash of java console, coming and disappear.

Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The JNLP file seems not formed correctly. Contact the provider of Jnlp.